# In android, how do you add an image to a master detail activity?

Tags: android, imageview, master-detail

I was trying to do a project about Recipes, and I want to display it using the master detail activity. I wonder how I can add image and more details into it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need help man...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into a basic android tutorial. Android uses xml files for views. You will need to go to the detail view fragment and activity and add an imageview (you can just drag it in from the graphical view). Now there will be an onClick listener for the listview in the master fragment + activity. Just swap out the image source inside the image view in the onclick listener to the image that corresponds with the list item.

get the image view:
ImageView iv = (ImageView) context.findViewById(R.id.idForImageViewInXml).

Then switch the image:
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.myFoodImage);